# Is there anyway to use an asterisk or other method in localstorage?

Tags: javascript, local-storage

This is a simple and dumb question. I want to use the localStorage.removeItem('itemhere') function. My situation is that I want to only remove localstorage items that all have a certain ending such as "_email". Is there anyway to target this? Perhaps like the universal selector * (asterisk) does? 
https://api.jquery.com/all-selector/

I have played around with * (asterisk) method with no result

These did not work for me so I am not sure if it is even possible.

```
localStorage.removeItem('* _email');
localStorage.removeItem(*'_email');
localStorage.removeItem(*' _email');
also a variable such as
var email = $("*").localStorage("_email");
```

The code is suppose to fit in a change function as follows.

```
$('.sar').on('change', function () {
$(this).closest('form').find('input[type=radio].rgroup').prop('checked', true);

        localStorage.setItem('all1', JSON.stringify(true));
        localStorage.removeItem('all2');
        localStorage.removeItem('all3');
        localStorage.removeItem('uncheck');
        localStorage.removeItem("* _email");

    });
```

I expected ALL localstorage entries ending with "_email" to be removed from localstorage while others are left in place.

Comment: Heh? What is localstorage? What are doing?

Comment: I am trying to locate a universal selector for localStorage.removeItem().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it manually by iterating over all elements within the local storage.

This gives all keys as an array from your localStorage object:

```
Object.keys(localStorage)
```

use filter, to filter them by your criteria:

```
.filter(key => key.endsWith('_email'))
```

and then remove them one by one from the localStorage:

```
.forEach(key => localStorage.removeItem(key))
```

result:

```
Object.keys(localStorage)
    .filter(key => key.endsWith('_email'))
    .forEach(
        key => localStorage.removeItem(key)
    )
```

Comment: BOOYAA! Awesome! This worked like a charm even without me having to edit my change function. Thanks ever so much. They need a way to tip people $ here on stackoverflow. Stackoverflow you need to implement a tipping system!!  Thanks again wiesson!!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for(let i = 0; i < localStorage.length; i++) {
    let key = localStorage.key(i);
    if(key.endsWith("_email")) {
        localStorage.removeItem(key);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello Antony, I need to add this into my change function. I will paste the code above.